# How do you create a Resource for a Step Function StateMachine using YAML?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, state-machine, aws-step-functions

EDIT: Trying to format this

I've created a working Step Function in the console, but I'd like to deploy the same functionality from a CFT. I've been scouring through examples, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer in regard to creating a Step Function StateMachine with the definition alone.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to call the step function via API Gateway and be able to pass it parameters with the call. This is what I have so far, my questions are:

1. Do I need to replace all of the "$.variable.otherVariable" things with curly braces? As in ${variable.otherVariable}?
2. Do I need to do the same for the keys of those values?
3. How would I go about setting up the API gateway path for a step function, or is it the same way I'd do it for lambdas?

RandomSM:
Type: "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine"
Properties:
StateMachineName: !Join ["", ["RandomStateMachine1-" , !FindInMap [StageMap, !Ref Stage, ENV]]]
RoleArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::customLambdaRole'
StateMachineType: STANDARD
DefinitionString: !Sub {"StartAt":"RandomStateMachine1","States":{"RandomStateMachine1":{"Type":"Task","Resource":"arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke","Parameters":{"FunctionName":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:RandomStateMachine1-dev:$LATEST","Payload.$":"$"},"Retry":[{"ErrorEquals":["Lambda.ServiceException","Lambda.AWSLambdaException","Lambda.SdkClientException","Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"],"IntervalSeconds":1,"MaxAttempts":1,"BackoffRate":1}],"ResultSelector":{"start_date.$":"$.Payload.body.payload[0]","end_date.$":"$.Payload.body.payload.[1]","previous_iteration.$":"$.Payload.body.payload[2]","row_count.$":"$.Payload.body.payload[3]","httpMethod.$":"$.Payload.body.payload[4]"},

"Next":"RandomStateMachine2"},"RandomStateMachine2":{"Type":"Task","Resource":"arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke","Parameters":{"Payload.$":"$","FunctionName":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:RandomStateMachine2Function-dev:$LATEST"},"Retry":[{"ErrorEquals":["Lambda.ServiceException","Lambda.AWSLambdaException","Lambda.SdkClientException","Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"],"IntervalSeconds":1,"MaxAttempts":1,"BackoffRate":1}],"ResultSelector":{"start_date.$":"$.Payload.body.payload[0]","end_date.$":"$.Payload.body.payload.[1]","previous_iteration.$":"$.Payload.body.payload[2]","row_count.$":"$.Payload.body.payload[3]","httpMethod.$":"$.Payload.body.payload[4]"},

"Next":"Excess Records?"},"Excess Records?":{"Type":"Choice","Choices":[{"Variable":"$.previous_iteration","NumericEquals":0,"Next":"Pass"},{"Not":{"Variable":"$.previous_iteration","NumericEquals":0},"Next":"RandomStateMachine2"}]},"Pass":{"Type":"Pass","End":true}}}

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to help here.

First, you have several options for deploying the workflow you defined in the console using CloudFormation. As you have probably already determined, from within Workflow Studio in the Step Functions console, you can export your workflow definition to YAML or JSON. The [Step Functions documentation for deployment options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/development-options.html#development-options-format) can help you understand the options, but I think your case, the best will be to use the `Definition` property which allows you to embed the workflow definition natively into your template. This is way better than `DefinitionString` as you don't need to do the messy string creation. You can then use `DefinitionSubstitutions` to make some parts of your workflow definition variable.

Second, you can externalize the workflow definition to a separate file to make things easier to manage. This is most easily accomplished using [SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) as it will do the packaging for you. Here is [a simple example](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-stepfunctions-examples/tree/main/sam/demo-bulk-delete-s3-objects) where I've done this and note that your state machine definitions can be either json or YAML.

Third, in terms of hooking all of this up with API Gateway, I suggest you take a look at the [Workflows Collection](https://serverlessland.com/workflows) on [Serverlessland](https://serverlessland.com). There are lots of great community provided examples for common patterns. For what you are looking for, I think [this example](https://serverlessland.com/workflows/web-contact-form-processor) will likely be a good place to start.